# How to stop scanf from parsing the integral part when the input is a float

Tags: c, floating-point, integer

So this program is a simple decimal to binary converter.

I want my code to repeat until user presses `ctrl + D`. I also want to let the user know that the number input is not a positive whole number if they put in a number like `-2` or `1.1`.

The problem is when they enter a `float` my code just infinitely prints my first print statement.

This is my code:

```
void DecToBin(int userInput){
   int binary[32];
   int i = 0;
   while (userInput > 0) {
       binary[i] = userInput % 2;
       userInput /= 2;
       i++;
   }

   for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; --j) {
       printf("%d", binary[j]);
   }
}
```

```
int main(void) {
    int userDec;
    int res;
    
    while(1) {
        printf("Please enter a positive whole number (or EOF to quit): ");
        res = scanf("%d", &userDec);
        res = (int)(res);
        if (res == EOF) break;
        else {
            if (!((userDec > 0) && (userDec % 1 == 0))) {
                printf("Sorry, that was not a positive whole number.\n");
            }
            else {
                printf("%d (base-10) is equivalent to ", res);
                DecToBin(userDec);
                printf(" (base-2)!");
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    
    return 0; 
}
```

So when I input something like `11.1` or a negative value it shouldn't accept it and print `"Please enter a positive whole number (or EOF to quit)"` in the terminal.

Inputs like `11.0` should be accepted.

So, I what I'm asking is what is wrong with my code that makes it do this, and how should I fix it? Should I use a `float` instead?

Comment: What condition is `userDec % 1 == 0` supposed to be testing? Surely dividing by `1` *always* leaves a remainder of `0`.

Comment: your scanf function expects to get an integer not float or double type. I assume you do not have the same problem for integer inputs. You may need a separate function convert fractional section to binary as well.

Comment: It's because `scanf("%d",&userDec);` takes characters out of the input until it finds a character that doesn't match the format string.  So, if you enter `12.34` scanf takes the `1` and `2` and then finds a `.` but a decimal point isn't allowed in the `%d` format so it stops taking characters.  Then you convert the `12` and go back to the scanf but the first character scanf finds is `.` and it can't use that so it stops.  But you don't check the return code.  To fix it, check the return code for scanf and if it fails then fgets the rest of the line to collect the `.34\n` and then scanf again.

Comment: `res = (int)(res);` - this is a totally useless statement. What was it intended to do?

Comment: @JohnColeman in JS, modulo 1 gives you the fractional part of a number.  Maybe its the same here.

Comment: @Amy There is no fractional part in `int`

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm aware.  But the OP seems to think he's inputting 11.1, a fractional number.  I think his code is intended to be testing a float.

Comment: @Amy OK, I guess OP should explain it. Even for floats it won't return the fractional part. You seem to be right though based on the context

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry guys my instructions told me that 11.0 should work, but also I want 11.1 to tell the user that that doesn't work.

Comment: You will benefit from the following answer [C For loop skips first iteration and bogus number from loop scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60472657/3422102) (describes how to use `scanf()` correctly)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin So since I want 11.1 to print "Sorry, … " should I be scanning in user input as a float, because right now my code just prints the "Please enter …" statement over and over again without stopping?

Comment: @osito_solito What I would do is declare a character array and use it as a buffer to read all input. e.g. `char buf[1024];`. Then read all input using `fgets()`, e.g. `fgets (buf, 1024, stdin);`. Now use `sscanf()` to parse the information from the buffer, e.g. `int i; double d;` then `if (sscanf (buf, "%lf", &d) == 1) { puts ("I have a double."); } else if (sscanf (buf, "%d", &i) == 1) { puts ("I have an integer"); } else fputs ("error: not float or int.\n", stderr);` Reading with `fgets()` and parsing with `sscanf()` ensures a *matching-failure* doesn't leave characters unread in `stdin`.

Comment: @osito_solito What is the largest acceptable value?  Do you want ot use `DecToBin(int)` and incur a limitation of `INT_MAX`?

Comment: @osito_solito Do you want `DecToBin(0)` to print nothing, `"0"` or not get called as perhaps you classify 0 as _not positive_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition `userDec % 1 == 0` is always true, the remainder of any integer divided by 1 is always 0.

When `scanf("%d", &userDec)` can't parse the inputed value, it returns 0, that happens when your input is not a number, you can take advantage of that.

To check if a value has a decimal part we can use `math.h` library function [`modf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/modf) which separates the fractional part of a double from its integral part and returns it, so yes, it would be a good strategy to use `double` (instead of `float` which is less precise).

(In Linux, using `gcc` you may need to use `-lm` compiler flag to link `math.h` header.)

Applying these changes to your code, you would have something like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
```

```
int main(void)
{
    double userDec;
    int res;
    double integral;

    while (1) 
    {
        printf("Please enter a positive whole number (or EOF to quit): ");
        res = scanf("%lf", &userDec);
        if (res == EOF) break;

        // if res = 0 input was not a number, if decimal part is 0 it's an integer
        if (res == 0 || userDec < 0 || modf(userDec, &integral))
        {
            printf("Sorry, that was not a positive whole number.\n");
            int c;
            while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF){} // clear buffer
            if (c == EOF)
            {
                return EXIT_FAILURE; // safety measure in case c = EOF
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d (base-10) is equivalent to ", res);
            DecToBin(userDec);
            printf(" (base-2)!");
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Considering your specs, an input of `11.0` will be valid with this code because its decimal part is `0`, while something like, for instance, `11.00000001` is not, because, of course, its decimal part is not `0`.

---

The above code has a vulnerability, if the inputed value is larger the `INT_MAX`, `scanf` does not have the tools to deal with it. If you really want to get serious about this, you would parse the input as a string and convert it with something like `strtod`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h> // may be needed for errno
```

```
int main(void)
{
    double userDec;
    double integral;
    char input[100];
    char *endptr = NULL;
    int c;

    // parse input as string
    while (printf("Please enter a positive whole number (or EOF to quit): ") && scanf("%99[^\n]", input) == 1)
    {
        errno = 0;
        userDec = strtod(input, &endptr); // convert to double
        
        // if negative or overflow or invalid input or fractional
        if (userDec < 0 || (userDec == HUGE_VAL && errno == ERANGE) || *endptr != '\0' || modf(userDec, &integral))
        {
            printf("Sorry, that was not a positive whole number.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%.0lf (base-10) is equivalent to ", userDec);
            DecToBin(userDec);
            printf(" (base-2)!\n");
        }
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { continue; } // clear buffer
        if (c == EOF) { return EXIT_FAILURE; }   // c = EOF, treated as unrecoverable
    } 
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Of course with something like this you would need to prop up your converter function to accept larger values, it now only accepts `int` as argument.

Either way all these input limits in your code should be conveniently documented.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry I guess I didn't explain myself to much in my original question. I wanted the input 11.1 to tell the user that it doesn't work. My code just repeats the "Please enter..." statement. So should I be scanning in as a float?

Comment: @osito_solito, yes, it's best to just parse it as `double` so we can check the decimal part, scanf just discards the decimal part, there are ways to check that, but it's simpler to use `modf` as shown in the code above.

Answer (score 1):

The most robust approach does not use `scanf()` to reads a *line* of user input.  Instead use `fgets()` and then parse the *string* with `strto*()` and friends.

Since OP is looking for valid input as an integer or as a floating point number with a whole value, construct helper routines to do each job well.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void base(int n) {
  if (n == 0)
    return;
  base(n / 2);
  printf("%d", n % 2);
}
// Return error flag, 0 implies success
int String2int(int *dest, const char *s, int min, int max) {
  if (dest == NULL)
    return 1;
  *dest = 0;
  if (s == NULL)
    return 1;

  errno = 0;
  char *endptr;
  long L = strtol(s, &endptr, 0);

  if (s == endptr)
    return 1;  // no conversion
  if (errno == ERANGE || L < min || L > max)
    return 1; // out of range
  while (isspace((unsigned char) *endptr))
    endptr++;
  if (*endptr)
    return 1;  // Extra text after input
  *dest = (int) L;
  return 0;
}

int String2Whole(double *dest, const char *s, double min, double max_plus1) {
  if (dest == NULL)
    return 1;
  *dest = 0.0;
  if (s == NULL)
    return 1;

  errno = 0;
  char *endptr;
  double d = strtof(s, &endptr);

  if (s == endptr)
    return 1;  // no conversion
  // Save whole part into dest
  if (modf(d, dest))
    return 1; // Test return of non-zero fractional part.
  if (d < min || d >= max_plus1)
    return 1; // out of range
  while (isspace((unsigned char) *endptr))
    endptr++;
  if (*endptr)
    return 1;  // Extra text after input
  return 0;
}
```

Armed with 2 helper functions that are picky about conversion, try one, then the other as needed.

```
char *doit(void) {
  int i = 0;
  char buf[100];
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
    return "Input closed";
  }

  if (String2int(&i, buf, 0, INT_MAX)) {
    double x;
    if (String2Whole(&x, buf, 0.0, (INT_MAX / 2 + 1) * 2.0)) {
      return "Invalid input";
    }
    i = (int) x;
  }
  printf("O happy day! %d\n", i);
  return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    doit();
}
```

Comment: @anastaciu Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `scanf` returns the number of successful conversions and assignments, or `EOF` on end of file or read error.

The `%d` conversion specifier will skip over leading whitespace and read decimal digits up to the first non-decimal digit character.  **If the first non-whitespace character is not a decimal digit, then you have a *matching failure* and `scanf` will return a `0`, *not* `EOF`.**

When you enter `11.1`, `scanf` successfully converts and assigns the `11` to `userDec` and returns `1`.  However it leaves the remaining `.1` in the input stream - that never gets cleared.

On the next read, `scanf` sees `.1` and immediately stops reading and returns a `0`.  However, you're only testing that `scanf` doesn't return `EOF`, so it never breaks out of the loop.

With `scanf` you're better off testing against the number of items you expect to be successfully converted - in this case, your test should be

```
if ( res != 1 )
  break;
```

I'd restructure your read loop as follows:

```
while ( 1 )
{
  // prompt

  if ( (res = scanf( "%d", &userDec)) != 1 )
  {
    // print error message
    break;
  }
  else
  {
    if ( userDec <= 0 )
    {
      // print error message
    }
    else
    {
      // process input
    }
  }
}
if ( res != EOF )
{
  // had a matching failure from bad input
}
else
{
  // user signaled EOF
}
```

Since the `%d` conversion specifier will *only* accept integers as input, and since `userDec` can only hold integer values, there's no need to test `userDec` itself for integer-ness.  The `userDec % 1 == 0` expression will always be true and is meaningless in this context.

If you want to validate that the user typed in an integer string vs. something else, then you'll have to do a bit more work.  You'll have to check the return value of `scanf` *and* you'll have to test the first character following what `%d` accepted:

```
 int itemsRead;
 int userDec;
 char dummy;

 /**
  * Read the next integer input and the character immediately
  * following.
  */
 itemsRead = scanf( "%d%c", &userDec, &dummy );
 
 /**
  * Here are the possible scenarios:
  *
  * 1.  If itemsRead is 2, then we read at least one decimal digit
  *     followed by a non-digit character.  If the non-digit character
  *     is whitespace, then the input was valid.  If the non-digit
  *     character is *not* whitespace, then the input was not valid.
  *
  * 2.  If itemsRead is 1, then we read at least one decimal digit
  *     followed immediately by EOF, and the input was valid.
  *
  * 3.  If itemsRead is 0, then we had a matching failure; the first
  *     non-whitespace character we saw was not a decimal digit, so the
  *     input was not valid.
  *
  * 4.  If itemsRead is EOF, then we either saw an end-of-file condition 
  *     (ctrl-d) before any input, or there was a read error on the input
  *     stream.
  *  
  * So, our test is if itemsRead is less than 1 OR if itemsRead is 2 and 
  * the dummy character is not whitespace
  */
 if ( itemsRead < 1 || itemsRead == 2 && !isspace( dummy ) )
 {
   // input was not valid, handle as appropriate.
 }
 else
 {
   // input was valid, process normally
 }
```