# getting input of variable length in C

Tags: c

So I'm writing a program for my C lab that gets user input for co-ordinates, in such a format:

```
-1.0 5.0

3.2 4.7

-2.0 3.4

1.0 4.4
```

and so on.

They are instructing us to use `scanf()` specifically, to get the input.
Anyways, the program will then do some calculations with these. However, I am stuck on how exactly to determine the size of the array I will store these co-ordinates in, if I am reading them with `scanf()` and storing them in the same function. Do I just create an array of size 99? What if they give 101 points then? Is there a way to read all the input first, count the amount of newlines, and then set that as the size of my array(s)?

This is my attempt:

```
void readPointsFindBoundingBox(double *bottomLeftX, double *bottomLeftY, double *widthp, double *heightp)
{
  printf("Enter coordinates: ");
double xvaltemp[25],yvaltemp[25];
int i=0;
while(scanf("%f %f/n", &xvaltemp[i], &yvaltemp[i])!=EOF)
{
    i++;
}
double xval[i],yval[i];
for(int x=0;x<i;x++)
{
    xval[x]=xvaltemp[x];
    yval[x]=yvaltemp[x];
}
for(int y=0;y<i;y++){
printf("%f",xval[y]);
printf("%f",yval[y]);
}

}
```

Comment: " use scanf() specifically, to get the input. " --> Too bad, `fgets()` would be a better approach - especially for error handling.  BTW, who are "They"?

Comment: professors! Its a beginner C course, so they have only really shown us scanf yet. I'm assuming thats why.

Comment: `scanf` is fine to use while you're learning.  And then after you develop some `scanf`-related headaches, then maybe you should look into utilizing `fgets`.

Comment: `scanf()` is so full of pitfalls for the new C programmer, it really calls into question whether the professor actually knows what he is teaching --- or if he is just using someone else's syllabus... You can use `scanf()`, but you must be intimately familiar with the whitespace handling of each conversion specifier and know how to extract any offending characters from `stdin` following a *matching-failure*. Otherwise -- watch out for infinite loops...

Comment: thats exactly the problem I'm facing with the code snippet I've attached. My while loop does not detect an EOF condition in scanf! HOw should I fix this?

Comment: _"HOw should I fix this?"_  use a flag value.  i.e. enter 9999.0, then test whether `fabs(val-9999) < 0.00;`

Comment: Why are all parameters `double *bottomLeftX, double *bottomLeftY, double *widthp, double *heightp`, *Unused* in your function? I presume `double *widthp, double *heightp` are just pointers to `double` values passed as `&somewidth` and `&someheight`, (which should not be `double` if they are indexes, but rather `size_t`), but how are the original variables passed as `double *bottomLeftX` and  `double *bottomLeftY` declared back in the calling function? Are they simple `double` values which you hope to update the value at that address with the actual bottom-left/right coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `malloc` then `realloc` to resize your array. This simple example shows you how it works. Note that I don't know how your user is supposed to indicate how they're done entering data, or what your data type/struct name is called, so you will have to modify this.

```
int i = 0;
size_t cb = sizeof(Point);
Point *points = malloc(cb), *tmp = NULL;

while(user_isnt_done_yet)
{
    scanf(" %...", points + i);
    cb += sizeof(Point);
    tmp = realloc(points, cb);
    if(tmp != NULL)
    {
        points = tmp;
    }
    else
    {
        // Out of memory error
    }
    i++;
}

free(points);
points = NULL;
```

Also note reallocating on every single entry is inefficient. I'd prefer to would start with a predefined size, and reallocate that by multiplying its size by 2 whenever necessary.

Comment: _Note that I don't know how your user is supposed to indicate how they're done entering data_
thank you! the portal we're using to submit homework is weird, so while(scanf()!=EOF) works, oddly enough.

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways of doing this:

- Increase the array size as needed. This is what most everyone does, static-sized arrays are nothing but memory corruption waiting to happen.
- Read the file twice, once to count the number of items and a second time to actually read the numbers in a properly-sized array. This is what most non-I/O C-style APIs do (DirectX, Vulkan, etc).

Comment: The input in this case is coming from stdin, as in the keyboard and not a file. The user enters coordinates and then presses enter. Two enters to indicate EOF. I can store this input as a variable and then read it twice. However, what type of variable would I have to store it in?

Comment: There's a third way — allocate more space than you expect to need and keep track of how much you use, complaining and stopping if there is too much data.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that's what #1 is alluding to, only instead of memory corruption you just refuse to do the job assigned to you. Personally I prefer to increase the array size as long as there's RAM.

Answer (score 1):

> *"...However, I am stuck on how exactly to determine the size of the array I will store these co-ordinates in, if I am reading them with
> scanf() and storing them in the same function., ...Is there a way to
> read all the input first, count the amount of newlines, and then set
> that as the size of my array(s)?"*

Yes, there is a way to do this.  And actually, as comments and other answers clearly show, there are many ways to do this task, even while being limited to using `scanf()`.  The following set of steps are one way.  They illustrate code that will accommodate any number of inputs, without knowing how many ahead of time the user will input. A count of user inputs is tracked and preserved in an index variable, `inx` which upon exiting the input loop is used to create an array of `inx` `double`, into which the text inputs are parsed into...

The steps:

- create `char *tok = NULL;`
- create `char *endPtr = NULL;`
- create index `int inx = 0;`
- create `double input = 0.0;`
- create input size variable `int size = 0;`
- `scanf()` user input for value of `size` eg `scanf("%d", &size);`
- use `size` to create and a variable length array ([VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)) eg `char buffer[size];`
- loop on `scanf("%lf", &input);` statements to collect input into `double` variable eg `input`
- use `sprintf(buffer, "%l0.5f,", input)` to concatenate inputs into temporary storage.
- increment index ( `inx++` ) once for each iteration of the input loop
- exit loop when flag input is entered
- use value of `inx` upon exit to create a [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) eg `double array[inx];`
- use the following code to populate the array by parsing the string:

example:

```
int i = 0;
tok = strtok(buffer, ", ");//delimiters are space and comma
while(tok)
{
    array[i++] = strtod(tok, &endPtr);
    //error checking for strtod would be advised here
    tok = strtok(NULL, ", ");
}
```

Note this is a rough framework for an algorithm and is light on error checking but works for simple user input tasks when number of inputs is not known at compile-time.

Here is complete working illustration of the above steps:

```
int main(void)
{
    int size = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int inx = 0;
    char *tok = NULL;
    char *endPtr = NULL;
    double input = 1.0;//to avoid tripping flag value test
    double flag = 9999.0;//enter this value to exit input loop
    
    printf("Enter desired size of input buffer:\n");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    char buffer[size];
    char tempbuf[size];//to prevent collision in sprintf later
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof buffer);
    memset(tempbuf, 0, sizeof tempbuf);
    printf("enter input value:\n");
    scanf("%lf", &input);
    while(fabs(input - flag) > 0.000)//using flag value as exit criteria
    {
        inx++;
        sprintf(tempbuf, "%s", buffer);
        sprintf(buffer, "%s,%0.5lf", tempbuf, input);//concatenate comma
                                                     //separated inputs string
        printf("enter input value:\n");
        scanf("%lf", &input);
    }
    double array[inx];
    memset(array, 0, sizeof array);
    //parse comma separated inputs string into array of double
    tok = strtok(buffer, ", ");
    while(tok)
    {
        array[i++] = strtod(tok, &endPtr);
        tok = strtok(NULL, ", ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are doing, and you need to determine the lower-left coordinates and the width and height of a bounding box to surround the x, y coordinates entered by the user, then you do not need an array at all. All you need do is keep track of the lower-left and lower-right coordinates and use a couple of temporary `double` values to capture the max x, y coordinates entered by the user and then your width and height can be set by subtracting the lower-left coordinates from the max values.

(**note:** you may need to adjust your comparisons based on whether you are using a normal Cartesian coordinate system (x, y are 0 at the center) or Screen coordinates (x, y are 0 at top-left of screen). We will leave that to you)

You cannot use any input function correctly unless you ***check the return***. `scanf()` returns the number of successful conversions that take place based on the *conversion-specifiers* you include in the *format-string*. It can return less than the total if `EOF` is encountered before all conversions take place or if a *matching-failure* occurs. (e.g. users enters `"banana"` instead of a coordinate). When a matching failure occurs, character extraction from `stdin` ceases and the characters causing the failure are left in `stdin` unread. (just waiting to bite you on your next attempted input).

`scanf()` returns `EOF` on an *input-failure* (`EOF` encountered before the first successful conversion takes place). In addition to a *matching* or *input* failure, you must also handle additional or extraneous characters entered by the user beyond what you ask for (e.g. the user enters `"10.2 13.8 and other nonsense"`. Otherwise a matching failure will occur on the next input attempt.

For further detail on the conditions you must check every time `scanf()` is called, the the answer to this question [C For loop skips first iteration and bogus number from loop scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60472657/3422102).

Implementing your bounding box function along with the needed validations is fairly straight-forward. However, ending the input is a bit tricky with `scanf()`. In order to avoid setting some *MagicNumbers* for the user to enter to signify done, the user should generate a Manual `EOF` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl + d</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl + z</kbd> on windows). Then you can process the `EOF` normally while still retaining the full range of possible inputs. (**note:** using the recommended method of input `fgets()/sscanf()`, the user need only press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on an empty line to indicate they are done)

With that in mind, you can implement your function as follows:

```
#include <float.h>      /* for `DBL_MAX` macro */
...
void readPointsFindBoundingBox (double *bottomLeftX, double *bottomLeftY, 
                                double *widthp, double *heightp)
{
    /* temp values for parameters, initialized to max/min of range */
    double x = DBL_MAX, y = DBL_MAX, x_max = DBL_MIN, y_max = DBL_MIN;
    
    *bottomLeftX = *bottomLeftY = DBL_MAX;  /* initialize parameter values */
    *widthp = *heightp = 0;
    
    puts ("Press Ctrl+D (or Ctrl+z on windows twice) when done\n");
    
    for (;;) {      /* loop continually taking input */
        
        int rtn;    /* variable to save scanf() return */
        
        fputs ("Enter coordinates (\"X Y\"): ", stdout);    /* prompt for coordinates */
        
        rtn = scanf ("%lf %lf", &x, &y);    /* read input, save return */
        
        if (rtn == EOF) {                   /* check if user done */
            puts ("(input done)");
            break;
        }
        /* empty remaining characters from stdin */
        for (int c = getchar(); c != '\n'; c = getchar()) {}
        
        /* validate EVERY user-input. 2 valid conversions required. */
        if (rtn != 2) { /* handle matching-failure */
            fputs ("  error: invalid double values.\n", stderr);
            continue;
        }
        
        if (x < *bottomLeftX)           /* set bottomLeftX/Y as minimum coordinate  */
            *bottomLeftX = x;           /* assumes lower-left is minimum coordinate */
        if (y < *bottomLeftY)           /* adjust '>' if Y increases as you go down */
            *bottomLeftY = y;
        
        if (x > x_max)                  /* track maximum bounding coordinates   */
            x_max = x;                  /* to calculate width, height           */
        if (y > y_max)                  /* adjust y compare if Y increases down */
            y_max = y;
    }
    
    *widthp  = x_max - *bottomLeftX;    /* set width and height based on */
    *heightp = y_max - *bottomLeftY;    /* coordinates input by user    */
}
```

(**note:** this presumes the pointers `double *bottomLeftX, double *bottomLeftY, double *widthp, double *heightp` are all simple  `double` values back in the calling function for which the address has been passed to your function)

To test your function you can write a short `main()` and add `#include <stdio.h>` to the top, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* additional include and your function go here */

int main (void) {
    
    double bottomleft, bottomright, width, height;
    
    readPointsFindBoundingBox (&bottomleft, &bottomright, &width, &height);
    
    printf ("\nBounding Box\n"
            "  Lower Left Coordinates (x, y):  (%.2lf, %.2lf)\n"
            "  Height, Width (height, width):  (%.2lf, %.2lf)\n",
            bottomleft, bottomright, width, height);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/boundingboxfn
Press Ctrl+D (or Ctrl+z on windows twice) when done

Enter coordinates ("X Y"): 5.2 3
Enter coordinates ("X Y"): 9.1 -1
Enter coordinates ("X Y"): 2.2 3.3
Enter coordinates ("X Y"): .5 -.1
Enter coordinates ("X Y"): -1.4 8.1
Enter coordinates ("X Y"): my dog has fleas
  error: invalid double values.
Enter coordinates ("X Y"): 1.1 1.1
Enter coordinates ("X Y"): 4 -2
Enter coordinates ("X Y"): (input done)

Bounding Box
  Lower Left Coordinates (x, y):  (-1.40, -2.00)
  Height, Width (height, width):  (10.50, 10.10)
```

If you pick through the numbers, the function does provide the correct lower-left coordinates and the width and height of the bounding box required to enclose all coordinates. (recall the earlier note about adjustments needed if you are working in *Screen Coordinates* instead of a normal X, Y coordinate system with X and Y increasing to the right and up, respectively)

Let me know if I understood your issue correctly, and if not, drop a comment and I can help further. Let me know if you have any questions with what is done above as well.

Comment: `if (rtn == EOF) { `  what if `rtn == 0` or `rtn == 1`?

Comment: @mevets -- both covered by `if (rtn != 2)`

Comment: No worries --- not like I've never skipped over a comparison or two ... `:)`